# Redrawing plot on Basemap in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting a scatter plot on a Basemap.  However, the data with this scatter plot changes based on user input.  I would like to clear the data (only the data -- not the entire basemap figure) and re-plot new scatter points.

This question is similar but was not answered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429693/python-copy-basemap-or-remove-data-from-figure)

Currently I am closing the figure with clf(); however, this requires me to re-draw the entire basemap and scatter plot together.  On top of this, I am doing all of the redrawing inside of a wx panel.  The basemap redraw takes too long and am hoping that there is an easy way to simply re-plot scatter points only.

```
#Setting up Map Figure 
self.figure = Figure(None,dpi=75) 
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.PlotPanel, -1, self.figure) 
self.axes = self.figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1],frameon=False) 
self.SetColor( (255,255,255) ) 

#Basemap Setup 
self.map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119, llcrnrlat=22, urcrnrlon=-64, 
                urcrnrlat=49, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45, 
                lon_0=-95, resolution='h', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes) 
self.map.drawcoastlines() 
self.map.drawcountries() 
self.map.drawstates() 
self.figure.canvas.draw() 

#Set up Scatter Plot 
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119, llcrnrlat=22, urcrnrlon=-64, 
        urcrnrlat=49, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45, 
        lon_0=-95, resolution='h', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes) 

x,y=m(Long,Lat) 

#Scatter Plot (they plot the same thing) 
self.map.plot(x,y,'ro') 
self.map.scatter(x,y,90) 

self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Then I do an some type of update on my (x,y)...

```
#Clear the Basemap and scatter plot figures
self.figure.clf()
```

Then I repeat all of the above code.  (I also have to redo my box sizers for my panel -- I did not include these).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post some code? I'd like to see how the scatter plot is being plotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) documentation mentions that the plot() command returns a Line2D artist which has xdata and ydata properties, so you might be able to do the following:

```
# When plotting initially, save the handle
plot_handle, = self.map.plot(x,y,'ro') 
...

# When changing the data, change the xdata and ydata and redraw
plot_handle.set_ydata(new_y)
plot_handle.set_xdata(new_x)
self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

I haven't managed to get the above to work for collections, or [3d projections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10992442/1427975), unfortunately.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the comma on the left side of the equal sign in `plot_handle, = self.map.plot(x,y,'ro')` is? I know it's necessary, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @KShores It unpacks the first element from the tuple. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708292/meaning-of-using-commas-and-underscores-with-python-assignment-operator

Answer (score 0):

Most plotting functions return `Collections` object. If so then you can use `remove()` method. In your case, I would do the following:

```
# Use the Basemap method for plotting
points = m.scatter(x,y,marker='o')
some_function_before_remove()

points.remove()
```